# How to get json array values in android?

Tags: android, json

JSON response value looks like this `"types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]`. How to get the first value of the types or how to get the word sublocality?

Comment: It's not a valid JSON. Are you sure it doesn't contain curly braces: `{}`?

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov see this link http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=adyar&sensor=true

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov it's a JSON array.

Comment: @DoctororDrive how to get these values.

Comment: @DoctororDrive it's not. It's a part of jsong object but not valid json :)

Comment: whats the full json string , it's odd

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
String string = yourjson;

JSONObject o = new JSONObject(yourjson);
JSONArray a = o.getJSONArray("types");
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
    Log.d("Type", a.getString(i));
}
```

This would be correct if you were parsing only the line you provided above. Note that to access types from GoogleMaps geocode you should get an array of results, than address_components, then you can access object components.getJSONObject(index).

This is a simple implementation that parses only formatted_address - what I needed in my project.

```
private void parseJson(List<Address> address, int maxResults, byte[] data)
{
    try {
        String json = new String(data, "UTF-8");
        JSONObject o = new JSONObject(json);
        String status = o.getString("status");
        if (status.equals(STATUS_OK)) {

            JSONArray a = o.getJSONArray("results");

            for (int i = 0; i < maxResults && i < a.length(); i++) {
                Address current = new Address(Locale.getDefault());
                JSONObject item = a.getJSONObject(i);

                current.setFeatureName(item.getString("formatted_address"));
                JSONObject location = item.getJSONObject("geometry")
                        .getJSONObject("location");
                current.setLatitude(location.getDouble("lat"));
                current.setLongitude(location.getDouble("lng"));

                address.add(current);
            }

        }
    catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should parse that JSON to get those values. You can either use JSONObject and JSONArray classes in Android or use a library like Google GSON to get the POJOs from JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I would insist you to use GSON. I had created a demo for parsing the same map response. You can find the complete demo [`here`](https://github.com/lalit3686/GSONDemo). Also I had created a global GSON parser class that can be used to parse any response that is in JSON with ease.