# (Android)How to get data from JSON to show on listview

Tags: java, android, json, listview, gson

This is my JSON data

```
{
    "success": "1",
    "results": [
        {
            "type": "1.popmusic",
            "posts": [
                {
                    "music": "1.AAA"
                },
                {
                    "music": "2.BBB"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to click some kind of music such as I click "popmusic" on my listview and then,Intent to new activity to show music in popmusic ,From my json It have to show "1.AAA" and "2.BBB" on listview.

I can't get "posts" from my json.How can I get it.

This is `Blog1 Class`

```
public class Blog1 {
    String success;
    List<Post> results;
    public List<Post> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

}
```

This is `Post1 class`

```
public class Post1 {
String name;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

// Getter and Setter
```

This is `main class`

```
  private void showData(String jsonString) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Blog1 blog = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Blog1.class);
        List<Post> results = blog.getResults();

        mAdapter = new CustomAdapter1(this, results);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


}
```

Comment: Can u post the class used to fetch/store the JSON data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the in build android JSON library

Refer [How to get json array values in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708935/how-to-get-json-array-values-in-android)

Refer [android get json array nested in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748829/android-get-json-array-nested-in-array)

First you need to get results

```
JSONArray json2 = json.getJSONArray("results");
```

Then loop inside ( I am assuming 0 for first element )

```
JSONObject json3 = json2.getJSONObject(0);
```

Then you need to get posts

```
JSONArray json4 = json3.getJSONArray("posts");
```

Then gain you can loop inside json4

--- EDIT ---

I see that you are using Gson but your class structure should be

```
public class Blog {
    String success;
    List<Result> results;
    public List<Result> getResults() {
        return results;
    }
}

public class Result {
   String type;
   public String getType() {
       return type;
   }
   List<Post> posts;
   public List<Post> getPosts() {
        return posts;
   }
}

public class Post {
   String music;
   public String getMusic() {
       return music;
   }
}
```

In your main code

```
Blog blog = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Blog.class);
//I am assuming 0th item for both
blog.getResults().get(0).getPosts().get(0).getMusic();
```

If you are constructing a custom adapter then, assuming that you are going to show all posts for one blog entry then you can get all posts as

```
List<Post> posts = blog.getResults().get(0).getPosts()
```

And pass the **posts** to your custom adapter.

If you have two adapters then **blog.getResults()** for first adapter then clicking on an item of that adapter **results.get(itemindex).getPosts()** for the second adapter

Comment: How can I use getPosts() on function main?

Comment: I have added the main code, It is an array of objects which contains array of objects, which should accessed using index of index

Comment: I think it useful but I don't know what type of variable to use for it such as List<Post> results = blog.getResults().get(0).getPosts().get(0).getName();      can you suggest me for that.Because I need to send to customadapter.

Comment: If you want to send all the posts to an adapter simply put blog.getResults().get(0).getPosts()...... assuming you are going to show all posts for one blog entry

Comment: Ohhh,Now I can get it.Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON

```
{
    "success": "1",
    "results": [
        {
            "type": "1.popmusic",
            "posts": [
                {
                    "music": "1.AAA"
                },
                {
                    "music": "2.BBB"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is actually mapped to

```
public class Response {
    private String success;
    private List<Result> results;

    //getter, setter
}

public class Result {
    private String type;
    private List<Post> posts;

    //getter, setter
}

public class Post {
    private String music;

    //getter, setter
}
```

Then you can make GSON get a `Result` out of it.